# Laravel : Trouble with belongsTo into the same model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this model

When I try to reach the author's informations, I have

> "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$id"
>   "

```
class PostSignal extends BaseModel {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function send($data)
    {
        $data['userid'] = $this->author()->id;
    }

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

My user model is classic:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends BaseModel implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'last_connection', 'gravatar'];


    /**
     * Generate gravatar image
     * 
     * @param integer $size Size of the image
     * 
     * @return string Image
     */
    public function gravatar($size = 32)
    {
        $email = md5($this->email);

        return "//www.gravatar.com/avatar/{$email}?s={$size}";
    }

    public function Posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('BlogPost');
    }

    public function Comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('BlogPostComment');
    }

    public function signal()
    {
        return $this->hasmany('PostSignal');
    }
}
```

Comment: In `send`, try `$this->author->id` instead.  If that doesn't do it, please also post your `Author` and `BaseModel` models.

Comment: With only $this->author->id I have "Trying to get property of non-object". My problem is not BaseModel, I tried with Eloquent I have the same trouble

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do with `send` and how you are using it.

Comment: Is this a setter or what ?

Comment: In this model when I call the send method, I want to store the datas and send a mail. I'd like to do these things in model cause I want it's done automatically

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, however, I note two things: 1) You don't have the inverse relationship from `User` back to `PostSignal` and 2) if you're getting *"Trying to get property of non-object"* then User is not attached to your PostSignal (possibly because of #1, depending upon how you're loading).

Comment: bishop I have the relationship in the User class. Look the last method called signal.

Comment: You don't need inverse relation. The only problem is that you access relation object `$this->author()` while you want `$this->author` or `$this->author->getResults()`, which does the same. However, apparently you also don't have related `User` for given `PostSignal` that's why you then get `trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Second to last line `hasmany` should be `hasMany`.  Probably doesn't solve this problem.